# Факторы, влияющие на корректную работу getcwd

Tags: linux, c, файловая-система, syscall

При вызове ф-ии `getcwd` (Ubuntu 16.04 OS, gcc 5.4) возникает ошибка, указывающая на то, что исполняемый файл не связан ни с какой директорией - код ошибки - 2 `ENOENT`. В контексте вызова данной ф-ии его следует интерпретировать как:

> The current working directory has been unlinked

, о чем я, собственно, и сказал выше.

Набросал отдельную программку, где вызывается эта ф-ия - отрабатывает корректно, и на выходе есть результат, соответствующий текущему каталогу. Из этого делаю вывод, что в той программе, где я решил применить эту ф-ию есть *некие факторы*, которые влияют на ее выполение. Что подскажите ?

Например, в коде, ориентированном под никсы (приложение кроссплатформенное), при запуске закрывают потоки:

```
fclose(stdin);
fclose(stdout);
fclose(stderr);
```

Не могут данные действия стать той самой причиной, по которой getcwd работает не так, как я ожидаю ?

Comment: собственно ответ просто, кто то удалил каталог, который приложение считает текущим рабочим каталогом.

Comment: @KoVadim, а если я наверняка знаю, что его никто не удалял ?

Comment: @KoVadim, или, быть может, в дело вступают какие-нибудь temporary-catalogues ? Вообщем, спасибо, на мысль навели )

Comment: ок, Я думаю, Вы в курсе, что текущий рабочий каталог - вещь достаточно не постоянная. К примеру, под виндой его очень легко поменять, просто открыв "open dialog", перейти в другой каталог и закрыть по cancel/крестиком. Вроде ничего не поменялось, а все...

кстати, можно посмотреть на `ls -al /proc/<pid>/cwd`

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо Вам, полезный совет )

Comment: Я предполагаю, что когда Вы запускали **отдельную программку, где вызывается эта ф-ия**, то запускали её в командной строке. И возвращаемое значение было правильным.

А ошибка возникает в тот момент, когда Ваша программа запускается как-то иначе (например - cron-ом) от имени ДРУГОГО пользователя, для которого в файле passwd, рабочая директория либо не прописана вообще, либо задана неверно.